# Testfor selected item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to get a `testfor` command to find a player holding an item named `Key2A`. I'm in 1.12 and I'm using the command:

```
/testfor @p[r=100] {SelectedItemSlot:0b,Inventory:[{Slot:0b,tag:{display:{Name:"key"}}}]}
```

This outputs:

```
[00:58:14] shmevan8or did not match the required data structure
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `SelectedItemSlot` when you can just use `SelectedItem`! Also probably because you were testing for an item named "key", not "Key2A".

```
/testfor @p[r=100] {SelectedItem:{tag:{display:{Name:"Key2A"}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test for an item and execute a command at a person you will have to type these commands in a repeating command block:

```
/scoreboard players reset @a Key2A  
/scoreboard players set {PlayerName} Key2A 1 {SelectedItem:{tag:{display:{Name:"Key2A"}}}}  
/execute @a[score_Key2A_min=1,score_Key2A=1] ~ ~ ~ {Your Commands}
```

Before you do this you have to add the objectives:
`/scoreboard objectives add Key2A dummy`